# How to implement UPDATE request with RETURNING values in Spring JDBC

Tags: java, sql-update, spring-jdbc, sql-returning

I have UPDATE request in Java EE, Postgresql that returning 2 values.

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "UPDATE system.current_orders SET " +
                            "status_id = 3, " +
                            "taken_dt = now(), " +
                            "system_dt = now(), " +
                            "driver_car_id_taken = ?, " +
                            "driver_color_id_taken = ?, " +
                            "WHERE id = ?" +
                            "RETURNING aggregator_id, taxi_name_from"
            );
            statement.setInt(1, driverCarIdTaken);
            statement.setInt(2, driverColorIdTaken);
            statement.setInt(3,orderId);
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                aggregatorId = resultSet.getInt("aggregator_id");
                token = resultSet.getString("taxi_name_from");
            }
```

how can this be implemented in Spring JDBC to get 2 values in one UPDATE request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code already shows, the SQL statement works like a `SELECT` *query*, hence the use of `executeQuery()`.

So do exactly the same as you would with a `SELECT` query in Spring JDBC:

- Call one of the [`jdbcTemplate.query(...)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#i32) methods.

Behind the scenes, `jdbcTemplate.query(...)` creates a `PreparedStatement` and calls `executeQuery()`. It is nothing but a helper class for doing that<sup>1</sup>. A very *powerful* helper class, with lots of nice features, but that's essentially all it is.

<sup>*1) and for calling `executeUpdate()` too, or course.*</sup>